# Android Development: Name of this view

Tags: android, iphone

Hi, I am new to mobile app development, so forgive me if this seems like a stupid question.  The screenshot below is from the Sydney airport iPhone app. Could anyone please tell me what kind of View is that? I mean, the one with all the "To and From" info, like "parking" etc.? And is it possible to make such a view in Android?

[image: Screen]

Comment: As others said below..this is a custom ListView in Android. If you need a tutorial on how to get a custom listview set up, have a look here http://jadebyfield.blogspot.com/2012/10/custom-listview-with-textviews-and.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the UITableView for Android Project.

https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview

Comment: Thanks man! That's what I want.

Answer (score 3):

On Android, this can be implemented as a `ListView` with a custom list item view.